# Avoiding redirect server's url to www for specific url path

Tags: android, deep-linking, google-play-console, android-deep-link

I want to enable auto-verification of deep links in Android for which I need to host the file `assetlinks.json` on my server `https://mycompany.com`. This will allow auto-verification of my deep links when the app is installed. The problem is, we have redirect setup such that all requests from `https://mycompany.com` go to `https://www.mycompany.com`. As a result, when I put the file in the `.well-known` folder, it gets hosted on `https://www.mycompany.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json` which does not satisfy the requirement for Android's domain validator.

See domain non-redirect section here
https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/10710301?sjid=18198349224505489730-NA

So if I try to open the url `https://mycompany.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json` it gets redirected to `https://www.mycompany.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json` and the file shows up in the broswer, so opening the url in browser is not a good test. Rather, I can use `curl` command in the terminal to find out whats going wrong.

`curl https://www.mycompany.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json` will return with contents of the file but `curl https://mycompany.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json` will not.

I am seeing other companies being able to do that like say, Lyft.

When we execute the command `curl https://lyft.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json` in terminal, you can see they host the file correctly on their server without the `www` regardless of having a redirect in place for other url links, so if we put `https://lyft.com` it is still getting redirected to `https://www.lyft.com` correctly.

How do we acheive this? How can we keep the redirect and still put an exception for one such url path that has assetlinks.json in the end?

Comment: This likely depends on your exact HTTP server.  I'd suggest including that information and posting on [sf] instead; they know more about servers.

Comment: The HTTP server is Apache.